# Django Queryset not displaying all results related to a member

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

i am trying to show data related to order table

VIEWS.py

```py
class HBTYReadView(DetailView):
    model = HbtyOrder
    context_object_name = 'hairbty'
    template_name = 'accounts/modals/hairbty/read_hbty.html'
```

MODELS.PY

```py
class HbtyOrder(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
            ) 

    hbtycustomer = models.ForeignKey(HbtyCustomers, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    itm = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
```

URLS.PY

```py
    path('read_hairbty/<int:pk>', views.HBTYReadView.as_view(), name='read_hairbty'),
```

Currently showing a user with one order but not a user with many orders. THANK YOU

**read_hbty.html**

```
<!--nw-->
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Id</th>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Sessions</th>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Date_Created</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ hairbty.id }}</td> 
        <td class="text-center">{{ hairbty.date_created }}</td>  
        <td class="text-center">{{ hairbty.itm}}</td>      
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Should use `ListView` instead of DetailView

Comment: Thank you for the quick respone, just changed to ListView but the quersey just dissapeared

Comment: its currently showing all users and details

Comment: You need to override get_queryset and filter to your needs.

Comment: Kindly could you show me an example, Thank YOU

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Views.py, the correct way was to override the get_queryset and filter as @Marco advised.

Views.py

```
class HBTYReadView(generic.ListView):
model = HbtyOrder
context_object_name = 'hairbty'
template_name = 'accounts/modals/hairbty/read_hbty.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('read_hairbty')
allow_empty = False
paginate_by = 100

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = self.model.objects.filter(hbtycustomer_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    p_f = HbtyOrdersFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
    return p_f.qs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter'] = HbtyOrdersFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
    return context
```